# WKWebView - change viewport?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, ios8, wkwebview

I am currently running the following code to set the viewport of my WKWebView:

```
NSString* viewPortjs = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]').setAttribute('content', 'width=%dpx;', false);", (int) webView.frame.size.width];
[webView evaluateJavaScript:viewPortjs completionHandler:nil];
```

I can see that if the code finds the selector `viewport`, it'll correctly set it, but I want to add the ability to add this line to the DOM if it is not present. I am a noob when it comes to Javascript, so I'm not sure how to change this code to handle the case if that selector is not present and add it. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is the javascript that will accomplish what you want:

```
var myCustomViewport = 'width=320px';
var viewportElement = document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]');
if (viewportElement) {
        viewportElement.content = myCustomViewport;
} else {
    viewportElement = document.createElement('meta');
    viewportElement.name = 'viewport';
    viewportElement.content = myCustomViewport;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(viewportElement);
}
```

For your use case:

```
NSString* viewPortjs = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var myCustomViewport = 'width=%dpx'; var viewportElement = document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]');if (viewportElement) {viewportElement.content = myCustomViewport;} else {viewportElement = document.createElement('meta'); viewportElement.name = 'viewport'; viewportElement.content = myCustomViewport; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(viewportElement);}", (int) webView.frame.size.width];
```

Comment: Nice! But you are missing actually adding the viewportElement that you create in the else leg. It should have this:  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(viewportElement)

Comment: @Nancy Thanks for catching that, I updated my answer.